# How can I show that this inequality holds?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{i}{2^i} \le  3- \frac{2n}{2^n}$$

I tried to prove it by induction but it didn't worked out. Does anyone have a good approach?

Comment: At each step, LHS is increased by $n/2^n$ whereas the RHS is increased by $(2n-4)/2^n$. Now note that $2n-4>n$ whenever $n>4$ so just check the cases $n=0,1,2,3,4$ and the rest follows.

Answer (score 1):

By my reckoning
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{i}{2^i}
=\frac12\left(1+\frac{2}2+\frac{3}{2^2}+\frac{4}{2^3}+\cdots\right)
=\frac12\left(1+\frac{1}2+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots\right)^2
=2.$$
For large enough $n$, $3-2n/2^n>2$ so your inequality is then clearly true.
This leaves a few small $n$ to check.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=2^{-n} \left(-n+2^{n+1}-2\right)$$

Comment: You beat me to it. :) And this one _is_ easy to confirm by induction.

Comment: hello, this way is also possible

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry but it isn't very useful to give a result that we find it with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i%3D1+to+n+of+i%2F(2%5Ei))

Comment: why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Method I

Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nx^i=\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}$.

Differentiating with respect to $x$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^nix^{i-1}=\frac{(x-1)[(n+1)x^n-1]-x(x^n-1)}{(x-1)^2}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^{i-1}}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{-1}{2}[\frac{n+1}{2^n}-1]-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2^n}-1)}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}}$$

Put $x=\frac{1}{2}$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^{i-1}}=2[1-\frac{n+1}{2^n}]+2(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^{i-1}}=4-\frac{2n+4}{2^{n}}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^{i}}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^{n}}$$

Method II

Alternatively, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}&=2\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^{i+1}}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}&=2\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{i-1}{2^{i}}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}&=2\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{i}{2^{i}}-2\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}&=2\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{i}{2^{i}}+2\left(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)-2\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\\
-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}&=2\left(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)-\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2^n}-2+\frac{1}{2^n}\\
&=\frac{n+2}{2^n}-2\\
\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{2^i}&=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}
\end{align*}